# Class range regex in function list

Tags: regex, notepad++

I am attempting to define a parser in NPP's functionList.xml. My file is split up as such:

```
------------------
{{header}}
------------------ {

[subheader]

random text

}
```

And I'm pretending that the headers are classes and the subheaders are functions so that they will show up in a nice hierarchy in the function list, like so:

```
header 1
    subheader 1
    subheader 2
header 2
    subheader 1
```

XML:

```
<classRange mainExpr="^\{\{([a-zA-Z]+\s?)+\}\}" displayMode="node">
    <className>
        <nameExpr expr="([a-zA-Z]+\s?)+"/>
    </className>
    <function
        mainExpr="^\[([a-zA-Z0-9\\]+\s?){1, 4}\]"
        displayMode="$functionName">
        <functionName>
            <nameExpr expr="([a-zA-Z0-9\\]+\s?){1, 4}"/>
        </functionName>
    </function>
</classRange>
```

What needs to be changed about the `classRange mainExpr` (or wherever else the problem lies) in order for the headers to be properly searched for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone has the a similar issue, the fix is apparently just to use `funcNameExpr` instead of `nameExpr` inside the `functionName` tag.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't have spaces after the comma:

```
"^\[([a-zA-Z0-9\\]+\s?){1,4}\]"
```

Putting this spaces converts the 'intended' range to a literal string, so it will match `^\[([a-zA-Z0-9\\]+\s?)` then literally `{1, 4}` and then your `\]`.